# Libpython error while building YouCompleteMe

Tags: python, vim, shared-libraries

I am building `YouCompleteMe` plugin of vim, following this [document](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#full-installation-guide). When I run `make` I get the following error.

```
Linking CXX shared library /home/sagar/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/python/ycm_core.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is this error?
 
I have installed [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) to manage python versions. Is it causing problem?

Comment: Try to compile it with `-fPIC`. You should also have python 2.7 libraries available.

Comment: @Lawrence tried compiling with `-fPIC` it's not working, same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the linker point to the .so (shared object) file and not the .a (static lib) file.

You can do this specifying the flag when running cmake:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so . ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteme/cpp
```

Do mind that even though you're using pyenv, YouCompleteMe build may point to an undesired
python build as they are not correctly auto-detected right now.

If you're having this problem, you should probably also specify the Python header files correctly:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/include/python . ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteme/cpp
```

PS=(I'm assuming your headers are in that path, do check before)

Answer (score 6):

Since some paths were different on my system from the accepted answer (both the CMake and the python lib ones) I'm posting an alternate solution for the above problem:

1. Make sure to have a shared library version of libpython2.7.so

   ```
   $ locate libpython
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1
   ```
2. Either create a symlink to it from where CMake expects it to be

   ```
   sudo ln -s "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1" "/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so"
   ```

   or alternatively, as written in [YCM's build script code](https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/blob/master/build.py#L122), you could add additional CMake options to ensure the .so library is properly found

   ```
   export EXTRA_CMAKE_ARGS="-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1"
   ```

Comment: Had the same error trying to compile YCM, symlinking the shared library didn't work for me, but exporting CMake options did, thanks :-)

Comment: I had this error while compiling Caffe on my Ubuntu server. Creating a symbolic link solved my problem. Thanks!